# Managing Linux installation on a fleet of build servers with large code workspaces

Tags: server, configuration, clone, ansible

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Have many Linux servers for building Android Open Source Project and testing those builds using Android virtual device (either Cuttlefish or Goldfish/Emulator)
- Have all the Linux servers managed with the same configuration.
- Have all the machines with large code base checkouts (e.g. AOSP) with builds already, so that incremental source code fetch + build is as fast as possible.

What is a good way to:

1. Define what each of the Ubuntu machines are configured with.
2. Be able to quickly deploy updates to all machines
3. Be able to quickly deploy / setup to new machines

In a combination like below reasonable / possible to achieve this?

- Setup 1st machine. Define this my a combination of Ubuntu Server installer + post installation steps (like installing packages, syncing project source code, building the project, ...). The post installation steps are defined in an Ansible playbook.
- Live clone the 1st machine to other machines (e.g. like https://nikvdp.com/post/cloning-a-linux-install/ ?)

Are there other / better options than the above?

I'd also like to easily manage changes to this environment. Like, maybe 6-12 months later, there are new package / workspace requirements. I want to make these changes to the 1st machine, and then re-deploy to the other machines. Is the best way here to just re-clone the 1st machine (again) to the other machines?